# Appendix 2 for UK Spouse visa

Tags: resident-permit, uk-visa, eu-spouses

Do I still have to fill **Appendix 2 of VAF4 (financial requirements)** for UK spouse visa if i am applying in 2020 ?

Comment: Do you have any reason to suspect that you don't?

Comment: Because there is no information in the online application and the checklist say anything about it.